# Why is Kirrahe brown?

Tags: mass-effect

In *Mass Effect*, Captain Kirrahe looks like this:

[image: An olive-greenish salarian]

In *Mass Effect 3*, if he survived, he looks like this:

[image: A greyish-brown salarian]

Unlike Shiala in *Mass Effect 2*, Kirrahe does not have a "Why are you brown?" dialog option.

**Why or how did he so drastically change appearance?**

I'll accept either in-universe or out-of-universe answers, but for the latter, I strongly prefer well-substantiated information, rather than unsourced speculation about (say) the first *Mass Effect*'s graphical capabilities.

Comment: So, what does Shiala say about this? Maybe Shepard tried to avoid the question to prevent a diplomatic incident? J/K ;)

Comment: @Mario: Shiala tells you it was a side effect of the Thorian, which Kirrahe never encountered.

Comment: Ah, now I remember.

Comment: Some people on Internet who wonder about this think he may have just aged (the three years between _ME1_ and _ME3_ is like 1/12 of a salarians life), but I wasn't able to find a statement from BioWare on that.

Comment: Are you trying to say you wound not go to the beach for a vacation after everything that happened in the first game?! Salarians tan very evenly...

Comment: @Odin: Even the eyes?

Comment: ..........sure...

Comment: It's camouflage. Clearly the lower picture's background is more brown than the top one.

Comment: Hmm, if we want to go down crazy fan theories. The ME3 Kirrahe looks a hell of a lot like his old subordinate Commander Rentola. Rentola's coloration is a near perfect match, though he was smooth-skinned in ME1. Maybe he stole Kirrahe's identity.

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two different theories on this that I can find (I have not been able to find an in universe answer)

- Age effect - As Krogans change color as they age, so do Salarians. This is somewhat belied by the fact that only 3 years passed between the two shots, and there is no lore to indicate that they change color as krogans do.
- Under different lighting - There is a marked change in lighting between ME1 and ME3. The argument against this is that it is still pretty much supposed to be natural lighting throughout, so shouldn't change skin colors.

Other than that, the prevailing sentiment is simply that Bioware didn't care too much about the continuity at the time.

Comment: As support for the aging theory, I think Councilor Valern's face changes somewhat between ME1 and ME3, he looses the pink coloration to the lower area of his face. I can't find pictures with good enough citations to back it up though.

Comment: "Only 3 years" is nearly 10% of the Salarian lifespan!